# Remix rebuild after changes fails and shows old state

Tags: css, reactjs, caching, browser, remix.run

I have just installed and set up a version of the remix blues-stack.
I am currently playing with some styles and whenever I save changes, they don't get applied. Instead my browser view jumps back to an old version and the console throws a lot of errors. e.g.

```
ErrorResponseImpl {
  status: 404,
  statusText: 'Not Found',
  internal: true,
  data: 'Error: No route matches URL "/build/routes/_index-T4WO3R2N.js"',
  error: Error: No route matches URL "/build/routes/_index-T4WO3R2N.js"
      at getInternalRouterError (/Users/fred/Desktop/uni/master/geoinformation_in_society/GIS/build/server.js:41105:63)
      at Object.query (/Users/fred/Desktop/uni/master/geoinformation_in_society/GIS/build/server.js:40203:23)
      at handleDocumentRequestRR (/Users/fred/Desktop/uni/master/geoinformation_in_society/GIS/build/server.js:42233:39)
      at requestHandler (/Users/fred/Desktop/uni/master/geoinformation_in_society/GIS/build/server.js:42166:28)
      at /Users/fred/Desktop/uni/master/geoinformation_in_society/GIS/build/server.js:43352:32
}
```

I didn't change anything in the `remix.config`. It looks like this:

```
/** @type {import('@remix-run/dev').AppConfig} */
module.exports = {
  cacheDirectory: "./node_modules/.cache/remix",
  ignoredRouteFiles: ["**/.*", "**/*.test.{ts,tsx}"],
  serverModuleFormat: "cjs",
};
```

Any hints on this?

EDIT: I have just realized that it only happens when I manually refresh the page. After changes in the code, the browser rendered the right view...